# Filesystem operations through Thunderbird Extension

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I would like to do some operation on my filesystem through a Thunderbird plugin.
For example create a folder at a specific location and a text file, 
containing some data from thunderbird, in this folder.

As you know, Mozilla Extensions consist of javascript code.
So I looked for this, found some code about ActiveXObject, which is not working for Thunderbird.

Any ideas what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

First, read up on [extensions in general](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firefox-addon/info) (Firefox docs apply to Thunderbird as well, except for the Add-on SDK, which does not really work with Thunderbird; go the XUL overlay route).

Then there are multiple ways to perform File I/O, in particular XPCOM stuff and `OS.File`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I hope there is some info about creating, deleting folders etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet from my extension. I create text file in Profile directory and then I add some text into this file.

```
var path = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService( Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path + "\\";    
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); 

file.initWithPath(path);
file.append("settings.txt")
file.create(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0664)


var outputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream );
outputStream.init( file, 0x04 | 0x10, 0664, 0 ); 
var output = "some text here"
var result = outputStream.write( output, output.length );
outputStream.close();
```